# Can the verb "Transmit" be used with the noun "time"?

Tags: verbs, nouns, gerunds

I want to provide a description of a notation **X** as **"X = Transmit time of the disaster signal."** It means the time at which the disaster signal was transmitted.

**Question:** Is it correct to use the verb "transmit" with the noun "time"?

My colleague says it might be incorrect usage of "transmit". But he didn't explain why.

Should it be **"X = Transmission time of the disaster signal"**?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the word to be understood as a noun, because you mean "The time of the transmit".

But transmit is used as a verb in most phrases, so this is odd.

Transmission is used as a noun, so "transmission time" is better.

"Transmit time..." would read like an imperative expression telling you to "transmit the time, please".

Comment: Thank you very much.